# how i can get a value through key

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json

i want to know how i can get a value/numbers through key/username ?

look like that `console.log(acc.${username})`

> my js

```
...

app.get("/account", (req, res) => {
  loggedIn = req.cookies.loggedIn;
  username = req.cookies.username;
  if (loggedIn == "true") {
    db.list().then(keys => {
      if (keys.includes(username)) {
        res.render("settings.html", { username: username })
        var data = fs.readFileSync('2FA.json');
        var acc = JSON.parse(data)
//////////////////////////////////////////////
        console.log(acc.${username}) // i want to see a numbers in user name look like in here
/////////////////////////////////////////////
      } else {
        res.redirect("/logout");
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.render("notloggedin.html");
  }
});
```

> my json

```
[
{
  "youssefnageeb": 927342
},
{
  "youssefnageeb1":310686
},
{
  "youssefnageeb2": 105380
},
{
  "youssefnageeb3": 431816
},
{
  "youssefnageeb4": 484728
}
]
```

Comment: Please be specific on what you want. Explain what you've tried so far, what you were trying to get, and what happened instead.

Comment: Instead of `acc.${username}`, do `acc[username]`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing "data" is in the format mentioned above.

So, you can do

```
const index = data.findIndex(function isAccountRow(row) { return typeof row[username] === 'number'; })
if(index === -1) {
  return res.redirect("/logout");
}
const row = data[index];

console.log(row[username]); // will be the number
```